# Subsetting data between specific, identifiable rows

Tags: r

let's say I have a dataset like this, in this example with three columns. There are rows with texts, and in between such rows are rows with numbers (the data that I want). If I want the data between two specific text rows, how would you identify the specific rows, and subset the data between the rows? E.g., let's say I wanted the data between row with c's and row with d's.

```
col1 col2 col3
a    a    a
a    a    a
1    1    1
2    2    2
3    3    3
b    b    b
3    3    3
c    c    c
4    4    4
5    5    5
d    d    d
```

into

```
4    4    4
5    5    5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to subset the data based on the identical elements in all the columns, one option would be to  paste the rows with `interaction`, use `grep` to find the index of rows that match the string, get the sequence of rows between the index rows (`:`) and subset.

```
indx1 <-  as.character(interaction(df, sep=''))
indx2 <- grep('ccc|ddd', indx1)
df[(indx2[1]+1):(indx2[2]-1),]
#   col1 col2 col3
#9     4    4    4
#10    5    5    5
```

In the example provided, there is only instance where this occur.  Suppose, you have multiple instances, you could get the corresponding sequences between index of `ccc`, `ddd` strings with `Map`, subset, and `rbind` the list elements.

```
 indx1 <-  as.character(interaction(df1, sep=''))
 do.call(rbind,Map(function(x,y) df1[(x+1):(y-1),],
                   grep('ccc', indx1), grep('ddd', indx1)))
```

#### Update

I realized that there might be cases in the dataset where the "ccc" rows may not have a corresponding "ddd" row or there are multiple "ddd" rows etc.  In that case create an index ("indx2") by converting the dataset to a logical matrix (`df2!='c'`).  Sum each rows (`rowSums`).  The result wil be a numeric vector.  Here '0' indicates the row have all 'c's.  Negate the index (`!`) to convert "0" values to "TRUE" and `cumsum`.  Split the dataset (`split`) to a list after rows before the first `ccc` row. Check whether there are all "d" (`!rowSums(x!='d')`) rows in each list element.  If there is any row (`if(any(..`), then subset the dataset (`x`) based on the index (`2:(which(i1)[1]-1)`), finally `rbind` the list elements.

```
 indx2 <- cumsum(!rowSums(df2!='c'))
 lst <- split(df2[indx2!=0,], indx2[!!indx2])
 res <- do.call(rbind,lapply(lst, function(x) {
              i1 <- !rowSums(x!='d')
              if(any(i1)) x[2:(which(i1)[1]-1),]}))
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(col1 = c("a", "a", "1", "2", "3", "b", "3", "c", 
 "4", "5", "d"), col2 = c("a", "a", "1", "2", "3", "b", "3", "c", 
 "4", "5", "d"), col3 = c("a", "a", "1", "2", "3", "b", "3", "c", 
  "4", "5", "d")), .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3"), class = 
 "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))

 df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("a", "a", "1", "2", "3", "b", "3",
  "c", "4", "5", "d", "3", "b", "3", "c", "4", "5", "d"), col2 = 
  c("a", "a", "1", "2", "3", "b", "3", "c", "4", "5", "d", "3", "b", 
  "3", "c", "4", "5", "d"), col3 = c("a", "a", "1", "2", "3", "b", 
  "3", "c", "4", "5", "d", "3", "b", "3", "c", "4", "5", "d")), .Names 
  = c("col1", "col2", "col3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -18L))

 df2 <- structure(list(col1 = c("a", "a", "1", "2", "3", "b", "3", "c", 
 "4", "5", "d", "3", "b", "3", "c", "4", "5", "d", "4", "5", "d", 
 "c", "4", "5"), col2 = c("a", "a", "1", "2", "3", "b", "3", "c", 
 "4", "5", "d", "3", "b", "3", "c", "4", "5", "d", "4", "5", "d", 
 "c", "4", "5"), col3 = c("a", "a", "1", "2", "3", "b", "3", "c", 
 "4", "5", "d", "3", "b", "3", "c", "4", "5", "d", "4", "5", "d", 
 "c", "4", "5")), .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3"), class =  
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```